# Connect google Datastore to google Data Studio

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I want to use google's Data Studio tool to make visualizations for the data I have in the Datastore. But it is not available as a source of data on the interface. How can I approach doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) to fetch data using the [Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis). One thing to keep in mind here is that Data Studio only accepts tabular data so you will need to reshape your data using the connector code if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are pretty limited. You'll probably have to move/convert your datastore entities into a database that can act as a data source for Data Studio. The following link will help you get started:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/topic/6370347?hl=en&ref_topic=7441382

Answer (score 0):

You can export datastore data to BigQuery, which is available for data studio. There is more detail on this here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore

Open the BigQuery web UI in the Cloud Console.

Go to the BigQuery web UI

In the navigation panel, in the Resources section, expand your Google Cloud project and select a dataset. Click Create table. The process for loading data is the same as the process for creating an empty table.

On the Create table page, in the Source section:

For Create table from, select Cloud Storage.
In the source field, enter the Cloud Storage URI. The Cloud Storage bucket must be in the same location as the dataset that contains the table you're creating. The URI for your Datastore export file should end with [KIND_NAME].export_metadata or export[NUM].export_metadata. For example: default_namespace_kind_Book.export_metadata. In this example, Book is the kind name, and default_namespace_kind_Book is the file name generated by Datastore.
For File format, select Datastore Backup
On the Create table page, in the Destination section:

For Dataset name, choose the appropriate dataset.

In the Table name field, enter the name of the table you're creating in BigQuery.

Verify that Table type is set to Native table.

In the Schema section, no action is necessary. The schema is inferred from a Datastore export.

Select applicable items in the Advanced options section and then click Create table. For information on the available options, see Datastore options.