# Analyze data in Google Cloud Datastore using Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, looker-studio

I am new to databases, and have some data stored as entities in Google Cloud Datastore. I would like to be able to analyze and plot this data in a web interface, and it seems like Google Data Studio provides an easy-to-use way to do this. However, I'm a bit confused as to how I can actually use the two interfaces together; it seems like either Google Cloud Storage or Google BigQuery could be a middleman in between, but I'm not sure how this might work. Could anyone advise on whether using Google Data Studio would be the best approach to plotting/analyzing data in Google Cloud Datastore, and if so, offer tips on how I could go about this? There are a large number of tutorials but it seems like none that I've found have explained how to load data from the Datastore into a useable file for Data Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Data Studio connect to cloud datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110175/google-data-studio-connect-to-cloud-datastore)

Comment: This has been asked a lot. Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056916/connect-google-datastore-to-google-data-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Graham Polley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877278/graham-polley) says, the question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110175/google-data-studio-connect-to-cloud-datastore). The workaround to connect Cloud Datastore to Google Data Studio is to first export Datastore entities to BigQuery, as explained in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore).

Then see [this](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343) in order to connect Data Studio to BigQuery tables.

Finally in this [blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/04/how-to-build-a-bi-dashboard-using-google-data-studio-and-bigquery), there's a tutorial for building a dashboard with Google Data Studio and BigQuery.